# Google Eddystone UID

Tags: eddystone

I have a beacon which support eddystone protocol. And I see some app through which you can change the UID of beacon. Even tough when I scan my beacon with android beacon tool I am unable to register it as it says that "the beacon is locked". My question how it is possible to change UID when it is hard-coded inside a chip? I may be totally wrong. And also when I use eddystone validator app it display the becaon but the UID is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Look for a mobile app from the company that sold you the beacon.**  Identifiers are typically configured over a connectable Bluetooth service.  Vendor-specific apps allow you to enter a new identifier and send it to the beacon when it is in Bluetooth range.